# datastax java driver - how to configure LOCAL_SERIAL for lightweight transactions

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver, datastax-startup

We have DSE 4.8.7 cluster with 3 datacenters, 5 nodes each.
Ww have a keyspace with RF 3, 3, 2.

We're using lightweight transactions.

When performing operations that involve shutting down a node on the datacenter with RF2, we have issues with the lightweight transactions as SERIAL consistency level cannot be met.

Is there a way to change the driver to use LOCAL_SERIAL instead of SERIAL?

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways you can configure serial consistency level using the DataStax java driver:

**[At a per statement level](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.0/com/datastax/driver/core/Statement.html#setSerialConsistencyLevel-com.datastax.driver.core.ConsistencyLevel-)**:

```
statement.setSerialConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_SERIAL);
session.execute(statement);
```

**[Globally for all queries](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.0/com/datastax/driver/core/QueryOptions.html#setSerialConsistencyLevel-com.datastax.driver.core.ConsistencyLevel-)**:

```java
Cluster.builder()
    .withQueryOptions(new QueryOptions()
        .setSerialConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_SERIAL))
    .build();
```